# Android app development suggestion/ workflow

Tags: android, sample, demo

I am trying to develop an android application, which will allow the user to send his correct gps location to a remote server and can list his previous recorded gps locations from remote server.

I am a bit confuse about what to use at which level and how to integrate them together.
My specific question is:

Which library (if there is any) to use for sending data to remote server and to get data (which will be in json format)?

or is there any sample demo app??

Comment: Well, to your question exactly - JSon -> http://www.json.org/ . For the other part, getting and sending this location data is a piece of cake, but it depends from the device and several other factors of course.

Comment: Just contact the NSA.  They are already doing just that and I'm sure will be more than happy to share it with you.

Answer (score 1):

For creating a fully fledge application you need to maintain a Server database and local android sqlite database having same schema. There is a background service which can capture GPS location whenever device moves and can save gps location over local and real server. if device is on offline mode it uses it's local sqlite databse and will sync to server as soon as comes in online mode.

Answer (score 0):

you might try the [FlexJSON library](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/).

It is pretty nice if you need to deal with Serialization/Deserialization of Data.